# Tinkerforge RS485 Callback in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, callback, rs485

I want to implement a Tinkerforge ReadCallback function in matlab to log changes from a RS485Bricklets with four slaves. I am able to establish an IP-connection and if I input a value into the bricklet via Brickviewer I receive it in matlab but I don't automatically receive values with the Callback-function without manual input.

```
clc
clear all

global data

    
    import com.tinkerforge.IPConnection;
    import com.tinkerforge.BrickletRS485;
    import java.lang.String;

    HOST = 'localhost';
    PORT = 4223;
    UID = 'DKf'; % Change XYZ to the UID of your RS485 Bricklet

    input('Press key to start\n', 's');
    
    ipcon = IPConnection(); % Create IP connection
    rs485 = handle(BrickletRS485(UID, ipcon), 'CallbackProperties'); % Create device object

    ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT); % Connect to brickd
    % Don't use device before ipcon is connected

     % Set Mode to RS485
    rs485.setMode(BrickletRS485.MODE_RS485);
    
    % Configure RS485Bricklet
    rs485.setRS485Configuration(9600, BrickletRS485.PARITY_EVEN, ...
                                BrickletRS485.STOPBITS_1, BrickletRS485.WORDLENGTH_7, ...
                                BrickletRS485.DUPLEX_HALF);                        
                     
    % Register read callback to function cb_read
    set(rs485, 'ReadCallback', @(h, e)cb_read(e));
    
    % Enable read callback
    rs485.enableReadCallback();
    
   % Write "ASCII" string (Adresse und Befehl)  
   rs485.write(String(':9003015E00020C\r\n').toCharArray()); %SWA 144
    
   rs485.write(String(':8E03015E00020E\r\n').toCharArray()); %SWB 142
   
   rs485.write(String(':8D03015E00020F\r\n').toCharArray()); %SWC 141
    
   rs485.write(String(':8F03015E00020D\r\n').toCharArray()); %SWD 143
    
    input('Press key to exit\n', 's');
    ipcon.disconnect();
    

% Callback function for read callback
function cb_read(e)
    global data

    tmp_t = now;
    fprintf('test \n');
    fprintf('Message: "%s"\n', e.message);
    
    B = convertCharsToStrings(e.message);
    C = [tmp_t; B];
    data = [data, C];       
    
end
```